# this.state is not working in render() and there is no error found

Tags: reactjs

This is small code snippet. I am trying to use this.state , but its not working.

```
import React from "react";

import Header from './Header';
import Footer from './Footer';
export default class Layout extends React.Component{
constructor(){
super();
this.state = {name: "sanu"};
}
render(){
return(
    <div>
    {this.state.name}
        <Header />
        <Footer />

    </div>
);
}  
}
```

Comment: It should work.

Comment: what do you mean by doesn't work, do you get a plank page or only the state doesnt show

Comment: only the state is not working

Comment: can you console.log(this.state.name) in the render function and see if you get a value there, because I doubt that the state paramter is hidden by you Header or Footer

Comment: I tried console.log. It is not showing anything.Please let me know how to correct it.

Comment: It's working file. Thank you all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took your code and put it in a codepen

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JJXjPe#anon-login

It works fine. Are you running Babel?

HTML

```
<div id="app"></div>
```

JS

```
class Layout extends React.Component{
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {name: "sanu"};
  }
  render(){
    return(
      <div>
      {this.state.name}<br/>
          Header <br/>
          Footer <br/>

      </div>
    );
  }  
} 

ReactDOM.render(
  <Layout/>,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```